# Detect orientation change before onPause

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation-changes, android-orientation

I am creating a `custom Dialog` in a method outside of the Activity's `onCreateDialog` method. When the device's orientation changes, I get the usually leaked window error that many other people have gotten:

```
06-15 23:47:07.712: E/WindowManager(964): Activity com.betweenthehills.TestVideoPlayerActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44ef8438 that was originally added here
06-15 23:47:07.712: E/WindowManager(964): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.betweenthehills.TestVideoPlayerActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44ef8438 that was originally added here
```

I realize I need to dismiss the dialog before the Activity is destroyed; but I cannot re-write the Activity methods. Is there some way to detect an orientation change before the Activity `onPause>onDestroy` cycle start?

Comment: Make sure you use these functions and events to create and show dialogs in activities: onCreateDialog, showDialog, removeDialog, dismissDialog. Android will handle rotation by itself.